# Function's parameter variable as object

Tags: function, variables, parameters, actionscript-2

Is there a way / I would like to know how to use a variable dynamically.
My idea is to have a movieclip calling a function at the same time passing a parameter.
The parameter value will then be pass to the function for more script.

**How to make use of the function's parameter variable, use its value to execute as instanceName.method with in the function?**

Sample Code, I have two movieclip with instance names, box1 and box2.
once, any of the movieclip is press, the function will execute.

```
// movieClip, instance name : box1
on(press){
    _root.functionName(this._name);
}
on(release){ stopDrag(); }
```

- movieClip, instance name : box2, has the same code.
- there identity is being passed to the function through "this._name"

Finally, here is the code for the function. I trace "b" in order to know its value.
Added startDrag() to be able to drag the movieclip.
"How can I able to trace "--drag "+b while dragging the movieclip?"

Thank you in advance. I have thought of using this code. Is this allowed?

```
function functionName(b){

    trace(b+" selected.");
    startDrag(b);

    b.onMouseMove = function(){        // <---- please help
        trace("--drag "+b);
    }   
}
```

The code may look simple and useless :) This is not really the code I am working with. I am just trying to get the proper line to execute onmousemove inside a function.

```
function functionName(param_var){    
    object.eventMethod = function () {
        // some code here.
    }
}
```

**CAN I MAKE USE OF THE PARAMETER VARIABLE AS OBJECT?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the answer. Thank you for viewing my post.

```
//Having function that would dynamically manage parameters into object
//given that the object is found in the ROOT.

function myFunction(param_var) {
    // _root[param_var] => can be use as an Object regards to the parameter
    _root[param_var].eventMehtod= function(){    
        // some code here;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably build your code differently. Here is an example :

```
//Import Delegate
import mx.utils.Delegate;

//First you set the event with Relegate which will prevent from Flash scope problems
box1.onPress = Delegate.create(this, onBoxPressed);
box1.onPress.currentBox = box1;
box1.onRelease = Delegate.create(this, onBoxReleased);
box1.onRelease.currentBox = box1
box2.onPress = Delegate.create(this, onBoxPressed);
box2.onPress.currentBox = box2;
box2.onRelease = Delegate.create(this, onBoxReleased);
box2.onRelease.currentBox = box2;

//Function executed when the box is pressed
function onBoxPressed():Void {
    var box:MovieClip = arguments.caller.currentBox;
    box.startDrag();
    box.onMouseMove = Delegate.create(this, onMouseMoved);
}

//Function executed when the box is released
function onBoxReleased():Void {
    var box:MovieClip = arguments.caller.currentBox;
    delete box.onMouseMove;
    box.stopDrag();
}

//Function executed when the box is pressed and the mouse moves
function onMouseMoved():Void {
    trace("I'm moving my box");
}
```

Comment: thanks for this whole new way...
but how am I able to deal with box2, box3 and so on?

I actually need something that would allow me to access any of the boxes using a single function. if that is possible.

function onBoxPressed(/*can I have parameter here*/):Void {
    /*and use it here?*/.startDrag();
    /*and here?*/.onMouseMove = Delegate.create(this, onMouseMoved);
}

Comment: is **variable.method** allowed, where as variable is a parameter?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. I edited my answer with what you need.